# Making Customised UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

As simple as the question, I could't find a good answer to my question.
I want to make tab Bar items to be loaded from my NIB file, So I change it whenever I want.
I want my tab Bar to be something like that.
with my own custom fonts, alignment, as you can see there is no images it just Text only.
So any one can help here ?

[image]

Comment: I haven't been working with `UITabBarController` for quite a while, but you can use customized controls like these:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbarcontroller

Comment: You don't need to spec images with the standard control - you can use just text. You cannot spec alignment per se, but really, you need that. You get a lot using standard objects like UITabBarControllers ...

Comment: can you put some code here plz